# Copy datagridview data with image column to clipboard

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

Is it possible to copy datagridview with image column to the clipboard and paste it on excel. Cause I'm using copy datagridview to clipboard paste it on excel for excel exporting but the image column was not copied. Is there a way to fix this?

```
 private void copyAlltoClipboard()
    {
        //to remove the first blank column from datagridview
        dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGridView1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText;
        dataGridView1.SelectAll();
        DataObject dataObj = dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent();
        if (dataObj != null)
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
    }
    private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        copyAlltoClipboard();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlexcel = new Excel.Application();
        xlexcel.Visible = true;
        xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
        CR.Select();
        xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unknown how the `DataGridView` is filled with data. In the example below I used a `DataTable` with an `Image` column to fill the grid. You may need to adjust the code if you are using some other type as a data source to the grid. If the grid does not use a `DataSource`… then I highly recommend that you use one as it makes things much easier.

When you place an “image” into a worksheet, you use the Excel “Shape” object and the Shape object is NOT necessarily “INSIDE” any particular cell in the worksheet. The “shape-image” is placed “on-top” of the cells and may overlap numerous cells. After the image is placed, then you can set a property in the image to “move” with a particular cell or group of cells.

In addition, when using any “COM” references in your application (like Excel Interop)… then YOUR CODE will be responsible for managing the “COM” objects/resources your code creates. The current code is NOT doing this and will most likely lead to a leaking resource. You should “always” wrap the code dealing with the “COM” objects into a `try/catch/finally` statement to ensure that the “COM” objects get properly released in the `finally` clause. This ensures that the “COM” objects get properly released even if the code throws an exception. Just a heads up.

As already noted, we know that the images are not getting copied when the clipboard contains multiple items of different types … i.e. text and images. However it should be noted that IF a “SINGLE” image is copied to the clipboard, THEN, that single image CAN/WILL be properly pasted into a range in the worksheet. This is one way we “could” get the “existing” images into the worksheet. In other words, in this case we could use the actual `Image` in the data table and paste it into the worksheet. This would eliminate the need to keep track of the `image` paths, however, we would have to paste each image one at a time. This is the approach used below.

Therefore we might as well loop through the grid or better yet it’s data source and manually write each cell of data to the Excel file. The only thing we would need to know is “which” column(s) are the `Image` columns. We will have to handle those image cells differently by copying the image to the clipboard, then paste the image into a particular range in the worksheet.

So, if we can loop through the `DataTable` and write each cell to the excel file, the only problem(s) we may have would be… “how” are we going to add the “Image” to the Excel file and “where” are we going to add it? As previously noted, adding an image is going to place it on TOP of multiple cells depending on how big the image is, how big the cells are and where we place the image in the worksheet.

Example, since the `DataGridViewImageColumn` has a property which allows you to “stretch” or “zoom” the image to “FIT” the cell size, we will not really know what “size” the actual image is unless we check it. If we do not check the image size, then it is possible for a large image to completely cover many rows and columns in the worksheet and thus covering up the other data in those cells. The code below attempts to avoid this.

The code below does two things to help avoid having the images overlap any of the other cells… 1) we will resize all images to a fixed size. 2) we will adjust the column in the Excel file that will hold the image to make sure that the column width and row height of those cells will be larger than the image size we set in step 1.

Below is a method that takes a `DataTable` `dt` that we want to write to an Excel file, an `int` `imageCol` to identify which column in the data table is the image column, a `string` `xlImageCol` is a string to identify which column in the Excel file we want the image column to be. In this example, this would be something like column “B”. And finally a `string` `fileNamePath` as a full path and file name to save the Excel file.

Walking through the code… initially all the interop COM variables and an `Image` variable are created and set to `null.` These are the objects we must release after the Excel file has been created. In the `try` section, the Excel application is created, a new workbook is created and the first worksheet is set so we can write to it. First a couple of ranges are created and used to set the column and row sizes such that each image will fit inside a single cell in the worksheet.

Next is a loop through the `DataTable`… if the column is NOT an image column, then the code simply writes the text to the proper cell in the worksheet. If the current column IS an image column, then the code sets the range to point to a single cell. Then the image is resized and then set to a `DataObject` in the `Clipboard`. Finally the clipboard is “pasted” into the single cell range we previously defined.

After, the loops through the data table finishes, the code loops through all the shapes in the worksheet and sets each image’s `Placement` property to `xlMoveAndSize` to ensure that the images remain in the single cell if other cells are resized or the cell the image is in is resized. Bear in mind, this only works one way… the image will resize when the cell size becomes “smaller” than the size of the image. If the cell size is “greater” than the image size, then the image will remain at its original size.

And finally in the `finally` portion of the `try/catch/finally` statement, the code saves and closes the Excel file and releases all the COM objects in addition to the `Image` object.

Below is a full example of what is described above. In the example three different images of different types are used and I have posted them here for your convenience. Obviously you may need to change the file paths of the images when saved to your machine.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Below shows the form and `DataGridView` created in the code. Pressing the button will create the Excel file shown below the form.

[image]

[image]

Lastly, It is unknown if you MUST use Excel Interop. In many cases you have no choice. However, if you do have a choice, I highly recommend you use a third-party Excel library for this. I suggest you look at EPPlus. Some are free… others not so much. Excel Interop is notoriously slow and has other issues… just a thought.

```
DataTable GridTable;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  GridTable = GetTable();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = GridTable;
  DataGridViewImageColumn imageColumn = (DataGridViewImageColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[1];
  dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
  imageColumn.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  WriteDT_To_Excel(GridTable, 1, "B", @"D:\Test\Images\_excelWS.xlsx");
}

private void WriteDT_To_Excel(DataTable dt, int imageCol, string xlImageCol, string fileNamePath) {
  Excel.Application xlApp = null;
  Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = null;
  Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = null;
  Image image1 = null;
  Excel.Range range1 = null;
  try {
    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    //xlApp.Visible = true;
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets[1];
    range1 = xlWorkSheet.Range[xlImageCol + 1, xlImageCol + 1];
    range1.ColumnWidth = 20;
    range1 = xlWorkSheet.Range["A1", "A" + dt.Rows.Count.ToString()];
    range1.RowHeight = 80;
    int xRow = 1;
    int xCol = 1;
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
      for (int col = 0; col < dt.Columns.Count; col++) {
        if (col == imageCol) {
          range1 = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[xRow, xCol++];
          if (row[col] != DBNull.Value) {
            using (image1 = (Image)row[col]) {
              image1 = new Bitmap(image1, new Size(100, 100));
              Clipboard.SetDataObject(image1, true);
              xlWorkSheet.Paste(range1);
            }
          }
        }
        else {
          xlWorkSheet.Cells[xRow, xCol++] = row[col];
        }
      }
      xRow++;
      xCol = 1;
    }
    // lock each image onto the cells underneath it - in this case one cell
    foreach (Excel.Shape shape in xlWorkSheet.Shapes) {
      shape.Placement = Excel.XlPlacement.xlMoveAndSize;
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
  }
  finally {
    if (xlWorkSheet != null) {
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
    }
    if (xlWorkBook != null) {
      xlWorkBook.SaveAs(fileNamePath);
      xlWorkBook.Close();
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
    }
    if (xlApp != null) {
      xlApp.Quit();
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
    }
    if (image1 != null) {
      image1.Dispose();
    }
    if (range1 != null) {
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range1);
    }
  }
}

private DataTable GetTable() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("ImgCol", typeof(Image));
  dt.Columns.Add("Col3", typeof(string));
  FillTable(dt);
  return dt;
}

private void FillTable(DataTable dt) {
  Image img1 = Image.FromFile(@"D:\Test\Images\SO_1.bmp");
  dt.Rows.Add("1", img1, "Hello");
  img1 = Image.FromFile(@"D:\Test\Images\SO_2.jpg");
  dt.Rows.Add("2", img1, "Goodbye");
  img1 = Image.FromFile(@"D:\Test\Images\SO_3.png");
  dt.Rows.Add("3", img1, "");
  img1 = Image.FromFile(@"D:\Test\Images\SO_3.png");
  dt.Rows.Add("4", img1, "Whatever");
  dt.Rows.Add("5");
}
```

I hope this makes sense and helps.

Comment: thank you very much. Works really well for me. Have a nice day!